# Angular2 - Two way binding for input Field

Tags: angular2-forms, two-way-binding

I have an input field of type number. When the user enter multiple zeros (0s) and moves to the next input field, the multiple zeros should go back to single 0.

I have tried the following code in the plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/dyCp5ZMKOkZvcsw4F8og?p=preview

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value" type="number" class="form-control" id="valueId" 
(ngModelChange)="valuechange($event)">

valuechange(newValue) {
//newValue = newValue.toString().replace(/^0+/, '0');
newValue=parseInt(newValue.toString());
console.log(newValue);
}
```

Comment: your plunker having different code , Please check and update plunker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to set `0` as a string when the value is 0, and call function onchange instead.
like this

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value" type="number" class="form-control" id="valueId" 
      (change)="valuechange($event)">


if(this.value === 0){
      this.value = '0';
}
```

PS: No need to convert using `parseInt` and `toString()`

<kbd>[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nucm2i?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)</kbd>

Comment: Glad to know @shweta , if you get what you want please mark it as accepted and upvote it !!